# Scala: copy case class from common supertype

Tags: scala, generics, types, polymorphism

Let's say I have a base Entity trait

```
trait Entity {
  final val id: Long = IdGenerator.next()
  def position: (Double, Double)
}
```

which can then be extended with some additional(still abstract) functionality

```
sealed trait Humanoid { self: Entity =>
  def health: Double
  def name: String
}
```

in the end, there are concrete case classes with functionality mixed in.

```
case class Human(
  position: (Double, Double),
  health: Double,
  name: String
)
  extends Entity with Humanoid {

}
```

Having that, suppose i need to define Event trait, which encapsulates some action from one entity to another

```
sealed trait Event[A, B] {
  final val timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis

  def from: A
  def to: B

  def event: B => B
}
```

and now, there is a case class for some generic event, which works only on Humanoid entities.

```
case class TakeDamage[A <: Entity, B <: Humanoid](damage: Int, from: A, to: B)
  extends Event[A,B] {
    val event = (ent: B) => {
      //a copy of ent with some parameters changed, e.g. health
    }
}
```

This should be possible somehow, because all entities of Humanoid supertype will have the required fields(health).

Is there any typesafe and immutable way to do this in scala, without too much boilerplate code? Or is my abstraction completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The only "non-ugly" (i.e., not involving smelly tricks like reflection and downcasting) way I can think of is add `def copy(health: Double, name: String): Humanoid` to the `Humanoid` trait, and implement it in subclasses.

Or equivalently, something like this:

```
 object Humanoid {
    def copy [T <: Humanoid](from: T, health:Double, name: String): T = from match {
       case x: Human => x.copy (health=health, name=name)
    }
  }
```

There aren't many benefits to the second approach, and it is less safe (there is no way to enforce that every implementation of `Humanoid` will work with `copy`, you have to rely on convention and programmer's memory, which is almost never good), so I'd stick with the old, good method overrides, as long as you have access to the class implementations.

Comment: It seems like shapeless has an example on what i'm trying to accomplish. What is your opinion on that approach? [github link](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/basecopy.scala)

Comment: I don't know, reading through that code makes my brains boil :) I thought you were looking for a _simple_ solution ... If that's the case, this is certainly not it :D.